# ioctl() calls from within Linux kernel?

Tags: linux

Is it possible from within a kernel module to perform an ioctl() call?

I ask because for some time now, I have been trying to figure out how to properly take down a network interface such as eth0 with a kernel module I wrote. I have had no luck, I have been able to turn off an interface but the kernel does crazy after I do which leads me to believe I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Why do you ask? What for? It smells very bad and looks like a misunderstanding or a major design mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System calls can be made from the Linux kernel. The kernel provides wrapper routines to invoke system calls. link: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/understanding-the-linux/0596002130/ch09s03.html

Make sure you do it from process context. Though, such practice is often discouraged, I assume, you know your design best. Good Luck.

Comment: In practice, syscalls should usually *not* be made from the kernel.